# Sum all values of each month from JSON to Array

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to make a data visualization, I need to know how to sum all values of each month, there is JSON data:

```
var data = [
  {
    "created_at": "2016-01-06",
    "commission": "238.00"
  },

  {
    "created_at": "2016-01-12",
    "commission": "538.00"
  },

  {
    "created_at": "2016-02-02",
    "commission": "12.00"
  },

  {
    "created_at": "2016-03-06",
    "commission": "113.00"
  },

  {
    "created_at": "2016-03-18",
    "commission": "212.00"
  }
];
```

Here is algorithm to sum all values of comission each month:

```
var months = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

var date;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  date = new Date(data[i].created_at);
  if (date.getFullYear() == 2016) {
    months = months[date.getMonth()] += +data[i].commission;
  }
}
//excepted result would be [776, 12, 325, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
alert(months);
```

I couldn't figure out about this logic, it returned first index of comission or NaN. Excepted result would be array with added values of each month like this: [776, 12, 325, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

There is JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/md57g0qq/1/

Comment: Why do you prepend `months[date.getMonth()]` assignment with `months = `?

Comment: @hindmost I was making sure to update this variable. So it was confused,  then this answer is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. Change `months = months[date.getMonth()] += +data[i].commission;` to `months[date.getMonth()] += +data[i].commission;`

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/md57g0qq/2/)

Comment: The typo does mean you don't answer, but vote to close the question with the "simple typographical error" reason. Those questions aren't helping anyone, you should use the debugger instead.

Comment: @nicael This is my question, none of your business, thanks

Comment: @nicael I think this typo is what was causing a **logical error**, debuggers don't produce any errors for such things.

Comment: @nicael It's just your opinion, this is question and its algorithm and answer is helping anyone  and don't need to repeat question. It's my mistake, even debugger didn't help. This answer is useful.

Comment: It's still just a typo - OP was going to use `+` instead of `+=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [

  {
    "created_at": "2016-01-06",
    "commission": "238.00"
  },

  {
    "created_at": "2016-01-12",
    "commission": "538.00"
  },

  {
    "created_at": "2016-02-02",
    "commission": "12.00"
  },

  {
    "created_at": "2016-03-06",
    "commission": "113.00"
  },

  {
    "created_at": "2016-03-18",
    "commission": "212.00"
  }


];


var months = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

var date;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  date = new Date(data[i].created_at);
  if (date.getFullYear() == 2016) {
    months[date.getMonth()] = parseFloat(months[date.getMonth()]) + parseFloat( data[i].commission);
  }
}

//excepted result would be [776, 12, 325, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
alert(months);
```